pyqt5 bring the main window to the front
I made a GUI and used win10toast_click library to get an alarm. When I get an alarm, I want to click that alarm. And then I want to bring the main window to the front like you actually click that window. I tried several sugesstions, but it did not work well.
For example,
window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
window.show() 
window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
window.show()

or
window.setWindowState(window.windowState() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
window.activateWindow()

I thought it would be very simple. But I couldn't find the right answer.
If I click the window, it is shown on top. I want that.(not on top always.) Can anyone help me?
def check_exist(self):
    toast.show_toast("checking", "exist", icon_path='', duration=3, threaded=True,
                         callback_on_click=self.activate_window)

def activate_window(self):
    ?


What OS? I suppose you're on Windows, which prevents activating (bringing to foreground) windows that do not belong to the active process. Consider checking the static setWindowActivationBehavior() function of QWindowsWindowFunctions. If it still doesn't work, please provide a proper [mre].

Yes, I am using Windows10.
